# Too large to import

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a case study to analyze bike-share travel data. My plan was to download the previous 12 months of trip data [here](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).
*Specifically the first 12 .csv files on this page.

I first unzipped the files of interest. When I go to google sheets to file-import-upload and select my .csv files I encountered a problem. Some of the months were too big to import.

For example, the 202103-divvy-tripdata.csv has a size of 42,535 KB and it worked for me (as did all the .csv files with sizes below).
The 202011-divvy-tripdata.csv has a size of 45,121 KB and it didn't work (as with all those greater). Is ~45,000 KB the max?

Each file has the same number of columns (13) but with a different amount of rows. The 202103 file that seemed to be the limit had ~228,500 rows.

I appreciate any feedback. I am new to data analysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This problem your facing is because of the row limit in the sheets. You can upload or import your file by splitting it.  https://www.splitcsv.com Here you can split the large csv files and can upload them on sheets or excel.

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution

You may want to break a file into smaller parts and import them separately at the same spreadsheet OR at a different one.

##### Explanation

There is a [limit of file sizes](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) you can store in Google Drive:

> ​Up to 10 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for
> spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.[...] The limits are the same for Excel and CSV imports.
> When you convert a document from Excel to Google Sheets, any cell with
> more than 50,000 characters will be removed in Sheets.

I was importing multiple CSV files with 60,000+ rows and 7 columns to the same spreadsheet; a couple of them worked, but eventually I faced this error.  I just learned that I could import it to a new spreadsheet and continue my work.

*So, the limit is not only at the **source** file to be imported, but also at the **destination** spreadsheet.*

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't have to be an online spreadsheet, you can take a look at GS-Calc:
https://citadel5.com/gs-calc.htm
It opens csv files with up to 12mln rows. The free trial version is a 4MB setup file (which expands to ca 7MB after the installation and you can install it on any portable usb device). You can test the speed and memory usage with your files. (Which should be more or less instant for files of that size.)
You can also open non-csv text files, with any cell separators (including nulls) and without cell separators (that is, with fixed column widths).
Regarding analyzing, I believe you have all what's in the spreadsheets mentioned above, including pivot tables and any type of filtering.